# Use minion targeting within Jinja templates

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

SaltStack allows for precise [targeting of minions](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/targeting/index.html) on the command-line, e.g.:

```
salt 'prefix*' grains.items
      ^^^^^^^
```

Is there some way to use the same way of targeting minions within Jinja templates? I'd like to iterate over hosts targeted by the given matcher, e.g:

```
{% for minion in salt.minions['prefix*'] %}
                               ^^^^^^^
```

Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the [official help on using Jinja](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/jinja/).

Comment: What specific information do you need from other minions by iterating?

Comment: I need data from the pillar that can be selected using their hostname. I require this for a config file that should contain entries for every other host (matching a targeting criterion) than the one that the state is applied to.

Comment: [Pillar data](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3000/topics/pillar/index.html) by design is available to minions based on the targeting available in Pillar `top.sls`. Once this is configured as per requirement, there should be no need to target from Jinja.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address every use case. I also want to e.g. select data by grains. Their hostnames are not collected within the pillar. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the additional comments you posted, it seems you are looking for the [Salt mine](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/mine/index.html) functionality. Using Salt mine we can collect data from minions (to master), and use the data on (usually) other minions.

Salt Mine can be enabled in minion configuration file, or minion's pillar, but format is same.

**For the sake of example:**

Consider 4 minions as below:

```
web1.example.local
db1.example.local
db2.example.local
db3.example.local
```

Now in the pillar file (`db.sls`) for the `dbX` minions, I have defined two Salt modules as Mine functions to get hostname and additionally IP address.

```yaml
mine_functions:
  network.get_hostname: []
  network.ip_addrs: []
```

Note that the Mine and Pillar might have to be updated (`mine.update`)/refreshed (`saltutil.refresh_pillar`) for this change to reflect.

Now any of the above Mine functions can be referenced by the [Mine module's](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3000/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html) `get` function. Minions can be targeted in the usual way - wildcard, grains, compound, etc.

Sample `example.conf.j2` template where I render the minion id and hostname.

```
{% for minion_id, hostname in salt['mine.get']('db*', 'network.get_hostname') | dictsort() %}
Minion id {{ minion_id }} has hostname {{ hostname }}
{% endfor %}
```

This template can be rendered on the `web1.example.local` with below state:

```yaml
create-example-conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/example.conf
    - source: salt://example.conf.j2
    - mode: 0664
    - template: jinja
```

This will result in `/tmp/example.conf` file with the lines showing `minion_id` and `hostname`.

Comment: Appreciate your verbosity. Will check this ASAP.